# how to open ios gallery in Qt

Tags: ios, objective-c, qt, qml, gallery

i'm trying to open ios gallery with Qt , i found many article and answers . i test  them but they didn't work in ios(10) 
here are two links that are not working for me

[Link 1 : Open ios gallery with FileDialog{}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443114/photo-gallery-in-ios-and-android)

[Link 2 : Mixing Objective-c with Qt to access gallery in ios](https://github.com/benlau/quickios)

first link explained how to open gallery with FileDialog ,according to link and it's description :

> in iOS just create a FileDialog inside the QML file and set folder:
>   shortcuts.pictures. It will call the iOS gallery.

. below is my code but it doesn't work !!

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0


ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        visible: true
        folder: shortcuts.pictures

    }

}
```

second link , I couldn't compile it and i got this error

```
ld: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a(arclite.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld Debug-iphonesimulator/QuickIOSExample.app/QuickIOSExample normal x86_64
(1 failure)
make: *** [xcodebuild-debug-simulator] Error 65
14:05:48: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project quickiosexample (kit: iphonesimulator-clang Qt 5.8.0 for iOS)
When executing step "Make"
```

thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions for gallery are :

### Android

[1)Android Gallery](https://forum.qt.io/topic/59813/photo-gallery-in-ios-and-android/10)

### IOS

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.1


Rectangle {
id:rootOpenGallery
y: Global.getMaxHeight()
color: "transparent"
implicitWidth: 85
implicitHeight: openGallery.height

function visibleAnimation(visible)
{
    if(visible===true)
        animShow.start();
    else
        animHide.start();
}

PropertyAnimation { id: animHide;
    target: rootOpenGallery;
    property: "opacity";
    to: 0.0
    duration: 900 }
PropertyAnimation { id: animShow;
    target: rootOpenGallery;
    property: "opacity";
    to: 1.0
    duration: 900 }
Button{
    id:openGallery
    anchors.fill: parent
    //highlighted: true
    Material.background: "#00796B"
    Text{
        text:"Gallery";
        height: parent.height;
        anchors.left: parent.left;anchors.leftMargin: 5
        font.family: Global.fontByekan; verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter;
    }

    Image {
        sourceSize.height: 32; sourceSize.width: 32
        height: parent.height
        anchors.right:  parent.right; anchors.rightMargin: 5
        fillMode: Image.Pad
        source: "../../images/Gallery-image.svg"
    }
    onClicked: {
        picker.showImagePicker();
    }
}

ImageDialog{
    id: picker
    multiSelect: true
    onImageSelected: {
        for(var i=0;i<urls.length;i++)
            if(checkDuplicate(urls[i])===false){
                picListModel.append({"checked":true , "fileName":urls[i] , "upload": false,"errorDescription":""})
            }                
    }

    function checkDuplicate(url){
        for(var i=0;i<picListModel.count;i++) {
            if(picListModel.get(i).fileName===url)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

}
```